# QuickBooks: How to duplicate inventory items automatically?

Tags: quickbooks

Here is how I am doing manually.

Menu: "Lists" --> "Item List"

For items matching certain search criteria, do "right click" --> "Duplicate Item".

I would like to do it automatically using QBXML request. But when I search the programmer's guide, I don't seem to find related information using keywords like "duplicate".

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QuickBooks SDK does not have a "duplicate" command like you're looking for.

If you want to duplicate an item, you'll have to query for the item details, and then create a brand new item using the details you queried.